# dev-certs in arch linux(.net)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, archlinux, dotnet-dev-certs

So I started working with asp.net core on my computer running arch linux. When I was on mac, to get dev-certs to work, I would run dotnet dev-certs https --trust in terminal to setup dev certs. This only works on osx and windows. To try and get the certificates working I tried to do the following things:

https://github.com/amadoa/dotnet-devcert-linux

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=251330

These two solutions unfortunately did not work for me. Fortunately I found a workaround by allowing non secure connections over localhost in my browse, but I'm still wondering if anyone knows how to setup dev certs in arch linux?